# Boxplot error R Studio: Error in boxplot.default(x = cataract_opths$pop.blind.cataract, range = 100) : adding class "factor" to an invalid object

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a simple boxplot with the following data:

pop.blind.cataract
 2,994,231 
 17,038,617 
 87,572 
 2,130,689 
 2,425,043 
 26,551,580 
 8,332,035 
 377,354 
 2,554,610 
 8,734 
 128,809 
 396,198 
 619,308 
 25,922 
 1,944,676

I've tried both these commands and gotten both these errors:

```
boxplot( x=pop.blind.cataract, range=100)
```

Error in boxplot(x = pop.blind.cataract, range = 100) : 
  object 'pop.blind.cataract' not found

```
boxplot( x=cataract_opths$pop.blind.cataract, range=100)
```

Error in boxplot.default(x = cataract_opths$pop.blind.cataract, range = 100) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object

I can't figure out what's going on. There are no "NA"s in the data. They are numbers. Can't figure out what's going on. Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is in your data. With the commas cleaned up and put into a character vector (use a data.frame if you like), it would look like this:

```
pop.blind.cataract <- c(2994231, 17038617, 87572, 2130689, 2425043, 26551580, 8332035, 377354, 2554610, 8734, 128809, 396198, 619308, 25922, 1944676)
```

Now just `boxplot(pop.blind.cataract)` should do the trick:
[image: boxplot(pop.blind.cataract)]